# Свойство ConnectionString не инициализировано

Tags: c#, .net

решил подключаться к бд через класс и как обычно новые ошибки 
System.InvalidOperationException: "Для ExecuteScalar нужно открытое и доступное подключение Connection. Подключение закрыто."

```
using (Connction.sqlConnection)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Key_num FROM Users WHERE Phone = @Phone", Connction.sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phone);
            return (int?)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

я добавил Connction.sqlConnection.Open(); и выдало другую ошибку :
System.InvalidOperationException: "Свойство ConnectionString не инициализировано."

помогите решить)

вот класс подключения к бд

```
public static class Connction
{
    public static SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=D:\MDK\MDK\MDK\DB.mdf;Integrated Security = True");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен `using` здесь, даже возможно он все и портит, так как при повторном вызове этого метода `SqlCommand` уже будет очищена. И засовывать в статичные поля `IDisposable` объекты - плохая идея, потому что в этом случае для них надо вызывать `Dispose()` при завершении работы программы вручную.

Просто, без `using`

```csharp
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Key_num FROM Users WHERE Phone = @Phone", Connction.sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phone);
return (int?)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

А при завершении работы программы вызовите вручную `Connction.sqlConnection.Dispose()`.

Если же вам хочется сделать все правильно с одиночным объектом вашего класса на все время работы программы, то вместо `static` используйте шаблон программирования **Singleton**, материалов по нему можно найти очень много. Но внимательнее с ним, этот шаблон очень чуствителен к качеству реализации, и если быть неаккуратным, можно напрограммировать багов.